# How do you set ReadOnlyDirectories with systemd-run?

Tags: systemd

I'm trying to prevent Juniper Network Connect (a vpn client) from modifying `/etc/resovl.conf`, which I hoped to do with systemd-run. I tried:

```
systemd-run --property=ReadOnlyDirectories=/etc ./ncsvc -h <redacted> -u <redacted> -p <redacted> -f <redacted>.der -L 2
```

I get the follwing error message:

```
Unknown assignment ReadOnlyDirectories=/etc.
Failed to create bus message: No such device or address
```

I also get the same message running a simple example:

```
systemd-run --property=ReadOnlyDirectories=/etc env
```

How can I run a process with systemd-run and have ReadOnlyDirectories set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a process with `systemd-run` and have `ReadOnlyDirectories` set since [`v228`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/ddb4b0d3eb57292c38a76f9b977f73cea15448fb/NEWS#L5):

> A number of properties previously only settable in unit files are now also available as properties to set when creating transient units programmatically via the bus, as it is exposed with `systemd-run`'s --`property=` setting. Specifically, these are: `SyslogIdentifier=`, `SyslogLevelPrefix=`, `TimerSlackNSec=`, `OOMScoreAdjust=`, `EnvironmentFile=`, `ReadWriteDirectories=`, `ReadOnlyDirectories=`, `InaccessibleDirectories=`, `ProtectSystem=`, `ProtectHome=`, `RuntimeDirectory=`.

Answer (score 3):

You currently can't, not all properties are settable, but it's on the TODO list to fix this.

here:

> ```
> * allow implementation of InaccessibleDirectories=/ plus
>   ReadOnlyDirectories=... for whitelisting files for a service.
> ```

and here:

> ```
> * document:
>
> ...
>
>   - document in wiki how to map ical recurrence events to systemd timer
>     unit calendar specifications
>   - add a man page containing packaging guidelines and recommending 
>     usage of things like Documentation=, PrivateTmp=, PrivateNetwork= 
>     and ReadOnlyDirectories=/etc /usr.
>   - document systemd-journal-flush.service properly
>
> ...
> ```

#### Reference

- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/TODO#L443
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/TODO#L127
- http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2015-February/028130.html

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is a suitable solution for you, but `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf` makes the file immutable, hence preventing anyone from modifying it -- even root.